# How do I connect webapp with android app?

Tags: java, php, android, laravel, web-applications

So for a personal project I'm building a task management webapp using laravel framework, I've hooked it up to hosting so I can use it any time. but for the future I want to improve the application so that it can be used anywhere with a smartphone, I want to make the application but with an android application based. so my question, what do i need to make android app? can i connect my old webapp with the android app? or do I need something new so that both applications can work with the same database?

Comment: What you need is a webservice.  If you did a standard 2 layer web app (where the front end and backend are separate codebases and the front end makes queries to the backend) then it can likely be used as the backend for your Android app.  If you did something where there was no separation and UI and logic are integrated (a common failing of PHP based apps), then you're going to have a major rewrite/refactor on your hands.

Comment: yes, i am doing 2 layer webapp, so is there any recommendation for android based app language or framework which can fetch data from my webapp?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to create a native android app and use Laravel api endpoints, or you can create an app that is basically just a webview that loads your app url.